# Defining a lower bound for a specific problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, optimization

Assume $k=\frac{10}{s_m}$ and

$s_1^{2} + s_2^{2} +... + s_m^{2} = 44000$

$  s_1 > s_2 > s_3 > ... > s_m>0 $ , $s_{i} \in R$ , $1 \leq i \leq m$

what is the sharpest possible lower bound on $k$?

I can estimate a lower bound, but I would like to know how to find the sharpest lower bound? Specifically I don't know the definition of "sharpest" lower bound in this context.

$m$ is a constant, Here I assumed $m$ is $200$.

Comment: the 'sharpest lower bound' is generally considered the supremum of all lower bounds; in the context of your problem you're looking to maximize $s_m$ subject to the constraint (for this would minimize k, and no lower bound could possibly be attained)

Comment: It's hard to guess what you're asking about. What do we know about $s_i$? Are they integers or just real numbers? Also, any information on $m$?  Can you perhaps provide the full question as is stated in the source you are taking it from?

Comment: @ Pink and Floyd  , $s_m$ is a non-zero real value. I uploaded the image of the original question (12.1) from numerical linear algebra book. I was working on the solution and eventually got to the question I asked.

Comment: @Crimson    Be careful! Your answer necessarily depends on $m$!, if $m=1$ then $\sqrt{44000}$ is the sharpest  upper bound (infinum of all uper bounds) on m, but if, say, $m=2$, and $s_1=1$, then suddenly $\sqrt{43999}$ is the sharpest upper bound on m, do you see what i'm getting at?

Comment: @mb you are right. I edited the post. I didn't understand what you wrote. I can conclude $m$ cannot be more than $\sqrt{44000}$. Could we say something more?

Comment: I think writing the inequality for $s_i$ in wrong direction may have caused some confusions. I edited the initial post which was showing $s_{1}<...<s_{m}$ to $s_{1} > ...>s_{m}$. I agree in general the value of $m$ will change the lower bound. Here it is assumed m is a constant such as $200$. I don't see how this will help in identifying a better lower bound.